# AngularJS : Persistent entities (JSON objects)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm primarily a C# and Java developer. Quite a newbie to JavaScript and AngularJS.

I'm developing a web app and I want to architect the app in the following manner :

**Topmost layer** : The views and the controllers (JavaScript)

**Next layer** : A model layer which fetches information from the webservice, stores it (persistently) so it can be accessed anytime by the controllers. (JavaScript)

**WebService** : returns JSON objects (PHP)

**The Database** (MySQL)

My question is regarding the second layer. Is there a way to implement what I want with angular factories/services (or anything else angular has), without storing the information in a global variable?

For example, I want an employee factory/service which I can initialize from a controller by passing a employeeID. This will call the corresponding webservice endpoint and then store the JSON object returned by the webservice. Then I want to be able to inject this employee factory/service into any controller I want and access data like employee.name, employee.age etc.

Any help would be very appreciated.

I would be very grateful if your suggestion(s) did not require fake JavaScript classes. I get a headache when I try to think of "functions as objects".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and a service would be what you want to use.

This is a useful library that you can configure in a service to do what you need: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

You could also use Angular's $resource service:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

Or even Angular's $http service:
[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)